# Loglikelihood and gradient function implementation in Python

Tags: python, logistic-regression, gradient-descent, log-likelihood

With reference to the scientific paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.04289 I am trying to implement the section 7.3 referring to Optimising hyperparameters. Specifically the equation 35 on the page # 25 in the paper.

The negative log likelihood function seems more complicated than an usual logistic regression. I tried to implement the negative loglikelihood and the gradient descent for log reg as per my code below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

#simulating data to fit logistic regression model
np.random.seed(12)
num_observations = 5000

x1 = np.random.multivariate_normal([0,0], [[1, .75],[.75, 1]], num_observations)
x2 = np.random.multivariate_normal([1,4], [[1, .75],[.75, 1]], num_observations)

simulated_features = np.vstack((x1, x2)).astype(np.float32)
simulated_labels = np.hstack((np.zeros(num_observations), np.ones(num_observations)))

plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))

plt.scatter(simulated_features[:,0], simulated_features[:,1], c = simulated_labels, alpha = .4)

#add a column of ones to deal with bias term
ones = np.ones((num_observations*2, 1))

Xb = np.hstack((ones, simulated_features))

#Activation Function

def sigmoid(scores):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-scores))


#log-likelihood function

def log_likelihood(features, target, weights):
    #model output
    scores = np.dot(features,weights)
    nll = np.sum(target*scores - np.log(1 + np.exp(scores)))
    return nll

def log_reg(features, target, num_steps, learning_rate):
    weights = np.zeros(features.shape[1])
    
    for step in range(num_steps):
        score = np.dot(features, weights)
        predictions = sigmoid(scores)
        
        #update weights with gradient
        error = target - predictions
        gradient = np.dot(features.T, error)
        weights += learning_rate * gradient
        
        if step % 10000 == 0:
            print(log_likelihood(features, target, weights))
        
    return weights
```

The biggest challenge I am facing here is to implement the terms lambda, DK, theta(dk) and theta(dyn) from the equation in the paper. Theoretically I understand the implementation and I was able to solve it by hand on a paper but I am finding it hard to implement on python while using some simulated data (as shown in my code). Can anyone guide me in how this can be implemented?